# NIFI - Convert date with a updateAttribute

Tags: json, text, apache-nifi

I need to convert this date: 2023-08-03T00:00:00-03:00

To: 03/08/2023

With a updateAtributte..
Is there any possibility?

I need to convert this date so I can integrate the data correctly

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have the FlowFile with an attribute `date`: `2023-08-03T00:00:00-03:00`

**UpdateAttribute** processor:

- `formatDate` (dynamic attribute): `${date:toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"):format("dd/MM/YYYY")}`

**output**:

- `formatDate`: `03/08/2023`